# AngularJS unit testing with jasmine form validity in a watch breaking tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out whats I'm missing and after 5 hours of googling I'm not closer to the answer so this is my last shot.

I have a AngularJS app and in one of the unit tests I'm checking that a controller displays some data after a api call. My problem is I have a watch on that controller that is running some date validation and it is breaking my tests. If I remove the watch the tests pass fine. The error I'm getting from my tests is below:

```
Result Message: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateFrom.$setValidity('txtDateFromValid', true)')
```

This is the code my watch is calling:

```
$scope.checkSearchCriteriaDateValidity = function() {
     var dateFrom = moment($scope.searchCriteria.dateFrom);
     var dateTo = moment($scope.searchCriteria.dateTo);

     // check each date for validity
     if (dateFrom.isValid() !== true) {               
         $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateFrom.$setValidity('txtDateFromValid', false);
     } else {
         $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateFrom.$setValidity('txtDateFromValid', true);
     }

     if (dateTo.isValid() !== true) {
         $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateTo.$setValidity('txtDateToValid', false);
     } else {
         $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateTo.$setValidity('txtDateToValid', true);
     }

     // check if both are valid and if so make sure from date is before to date
     if (dateFrom.isValid() && dateTo.isValid()) {
          if (dateFrom.isAfter(dateTo)) {
               $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateFrom.$setValidity('fromBeforeTo', false);
          } else {
               $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateFrom.$setValidity('fromBeforeTo', true);
          }
     }
};
```

Can some point out what I'm missing. Do I have to do something special with my tests to deal with this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the Form into your controller?

Comment: I've not done anything to get the form into the controller. I thought Angular injected the form into $scope? My apologies here as I'm pretty new to Angular

Comment: As far as I know it does not. Does your example work in your app, outside of the test? You shouldn't really be using the Forms in your controller.

Comment: Thats the thing the code works fine when the app is run up and has been working for a while. Its just the unit test that breaks but its looking like the unit test is right and the code is wrong. Am I right in assuming any custom validation should be performed using directives?

Comment: You're right, you should probably be doing it in directives. See Custom Validation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

Comment: You could for example make a is-before-date="dateToBeBefore" directive and a is-after-date="dateToBeAfter" directive. And you just provide the model value to each other inputs directive. Hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: Thanks m.brand that makes sense to me, I'll look at refactoring this into a directive or two. I'm still curious thought as to how I have been able to reference the form and its controls though $scope   :\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63412/discussion-between-m-brand-and-chris).

Answer (score -1):

I hope my answer will be helpful for you. The problem is `$setvalidity` is a method which was in undefined while executing your method by jasmine script. In order to fix that, you have to create a mock method for set validity before u calling the corresponding method.

Please try the below code in it method,

```
 $scope.filterOrdersForm = {txtDateFrom : {$setValidity: function (var1,var2){ return true }}};
 Spyon( $scope.filterOrdersForm.txtDateFrom,"$setValidity");
```